# Why do people get credited for editing questions?

Tags: discussion, edits

I am getting very annoyed with people editing my questions for no reason other than to satisfy their own ego.  The changes make no material difference BUT mean I have to keep rolling them back.

Why do they get credited for this?

Common issues are:  Removing some spaces from end of sentences, editing the layout  and adding some parts as `<code>` that I don't want as code, rewording some sentences, but for no grammatical difference.  I always roll them back when I have time, but it's become more prevalent recently with what appear to be serial editors.

Comment: I've forgotten the threshold for no longer receiving points for editing, but some users may be a bit (ahem...) overenthusiastic in trying to get over that line. I seem to remember <ah, sigh...> that I would hop on typos and what might be considered trivial mistakes (but I never stooped to the level of deleting trailing spaces - a bit infra dig, what? :-) ).

Comment: Thanks @Vérace - when my post is unclear I don't mind - but when I can't even tell what the edit was  :(

Comment: Agreed - a bit OTT to say the least! Flag it if there are persistent offenders!

Comment: It's annoying at first, but you'll get used to it. Think of StackExchange less as an internet forum and more of a living textbook. You are getting help - and you will get help from some very good people. They are getting your question to add to their library. They may have their way with it before they put it on the shelf. Oh, you've been here longer than I have. Maybe you won't get used to it...

Comment: If you included some examples, one could possibly explain it better why these edits were done (and if they really made sense).

Comment: "Why do they get credited for this?" you sure this happens? Seems to me you've got to a wrong conclusion. As to why it happens - it's a collaboration site, you don't "own" your questions or your answers, every user can update questions and answers. If anything gets iffy, flag for a moderator. And get over it.

Answer (score 9):

Since I assume you're complaining about my edits to your [recent question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206967/find-the-maxdate-from-two-tables-in-the-most-efficient-manner), here's an explanation:

**Edit 1:**

Your question was about getting the max from two tables. I misread your code a bit, and thought the `UNION ALL` was supposed to bring the two results together. That was my mistake, and I rolled it back.

**Edit 2:**

I added the [sql-server] tag to your question. It's standard practice to tag your questions with the platform, and the major version. You rolled that one back, presumably because you:

> can't even tell what the edit was

I can assure you that neither edit was of any benefit to my ego.

If you don't like people editing questions to correct mistakes, or to make sure they conform to site norms, this may not be a good place for you to post questions.

If you have trouble not ascribing self-aggrandizement to people trying to help you for free, perhaps the internet isn't a good place for you.

Hope this helps you understand where I'm coming from.

Comment: Not just yours, I post under a different name from work and that is suffering too. Been on SO for years and it’s getting worse.

Comment: @BlueChippy Again, if you see an edit that you don't think was correct, flag it. Editing is a very important part of this site, and you will see it a lot, but we want to make sure it's right. Hand-waving about it isn't going to fix anything.

Answer (score 9):

Try not to be annoyed.  It helps no one, and complaining about someone trying to help you comes across as whiney.

FYI, I just edited several of your questions to correct grammatical inconsistencies.  Please realize this is only done to improve the quality of questions for the betterment of the entire site; both for *your benefit* and for the benefit of future visitors to the site.

Note, I get no "credit" for spending my valuable time on improving your questions.

Comment: Perhaps by credits the OP means the "edited <time> ago <nickname>" kind of signature.

Comment: @Andriy OP might be referring to the +2 that users without edit privs get for approved suggested edits.

Comment: In either case, if some kid walks by my house and picks a soda can off my lawn, then takes it to the recycling center and gets 10 cents for it, why would I complain about that? My lawn looks better and the kid is 10 cents richer, though if you proposed to the kid that you'd pay him 10 cents to take this can to the dump, he'd tell you where to go. Which is about the equivalent here - 2 rep points, only for those without edit privileges already, is not worth the time and the effort. It's about improving quality.

Comment: Thanks for that edit, @sp_BlitzedErik